# Bookmark manager for chrome that works with the existing bookmarks and allows things like making a new folder in the bookmark manager?

Tags: chrome

I'm looking for a bookmark manager for chrome that works with my existing bookmarks.

Ideally it would be tag based, but it has to convert the present folders tot ags.

It should be able to tag things in the bookmark manager, and to create or find a tag when making a bookmark.